# How to use projection buffers in Visual Studio to edit languages embedded in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, languageservice

The [projection technique](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885240.aspx#projection) can be used to customize the Visual Studio editor for supporting embedded languages. The examples available online, such as the [editor customization for Django](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ea113de-a009-46cd-99f5-65ef0595f937) support scripting languages embedded in HTML. The implementations seem to be tied to the built-in HTML editor.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to achieve similar functionality for languages **embedded in C#**? I tried to replicate the projection buffer solution used for the Django editor and change the content type from “HTML” to “CSharp”. The editor seems to recognize the C# content as “code” but does not provide syntax highlighting, IntelliSense, etc.